# Is it possible to package Experience Builder Pages

Tags: community, experience-builder-page

Pretty straight forward question:

> Is it possible (Today- Summer '20) to include an "Experience Builder Page", non-default, created from Experience Builder in a package (managed or unmanaged)?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the page from the Experience Builder Developer Section as shown below and then you should see it in both Managed and Unmanaged package.

[image]

Comment: Can you please suggest, the "component type" to search, while creating a managed package, for these pages to add to the package ( I mean for the exported pages from the above screen)? thanks in advance,