# Experience builder pages in managed package , component type

Tags: managed-package, experience-builder-page

after looking at this
[Is it possible to package Experience Builder Pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304199/is-it-possible-to-package-experience-builder-pages/379801#379801)

I am not sure about the "component type" to search, while creating a managed package, for these pages to add to the package ( I mean for the exported pages from the above screen)?

so in general, what are the next steps while creating managed package to include components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting a digital experience bundle's page, as mentioned in the referenced Q&A [answer by Mohith](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/304202/50252) turns it into a `flexipage`, named something like *Experience_Name*_*Page_Name*.

When installed (or otherwise available) on the org, the experience builder allows you to create new "standard" pages based on the flexipage. Here's an example where I exported the "Home" page:

[image: The "New" Home Page available when creating a new standard page]

Comment: thanks, Phil this helps, also can you please suggest how I can take a copy of all  Experience builder configuration /community configuration ( pages/navigation/user access to pages(manage audience) /other community settings etc.,) in the managed package... instead of recreating or re-doing all the community-related..

Comment: Putting it in a managed package is something Salesforce recommended strongly against trying. However, you could use an unlocked package approach like I cover [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347145/how-do-i-package-an-upgradable-experience-builder-site).